# Convert month name to month number in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In T-SQL what is the best way to convert a month name into a number?

E.g:

```
'January' -> 1
'February' -> 2
'March' -> 3
```

Etc.

Are there any built in functions that can do this?

Comment: it will help us if you expand your question and requirement a bit

Answer (score 42, accepted):

How about this?

```
select DATEPART(MM,'january 01 2011') -- returns 1
select DATEPART(MM,'march 01 2011')  -- returns 3
select DATEPART(MM,'august 01 2011') -- returns 8
```

Answer (score 24):

How about this:

```
SELECT MONTH('March' + ' 1 2014')
```

Would return `3`.

Comment: Not sure which one performs better

Comment: for others, note that '1 2004' is just a dummy date and year and can be anything, preferably some old date.

Comment: I get similar performance of DATEPART and MONTH tested on 670,000 rows.

Answer (score 13):

Its quit simple,
Take the first 3 digits of the month name and use this formula.

```
Select charindex('DEC','JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC')/4+1
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. I did modify this a bit to just divide by 3. '--JANFEBMARAPRMAY....'

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT DATEPART(MM,'january '+'01 1900')
SELECT MONTH('january ' + '01 1900')
SELECT month(dateadd(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,'january 01 2015'),0))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a function and then refer to it in the select statement.
The function may look similar to this:

```
if OBJECT_ID('fn_month_name_to_number', 'IF') is not null
drop function fn_month_name_to_number
go
create function fn_month_name_to_number (@monthname varchar(25))
returns int as
begin
declare @monthno as int;
select @monthno =
case @monthname
when 'January' then 1
when 'February' then 2
when 'March' then 3
when 'April' then 4
when 'May' then 5
when 'June' then 6
when 'July' then 7
when 'August' then 8
when 'September' then 9
when 'October' then 10
when 'November' then 11
when 'December' then 12
end
return @monthno
end
```

Then you can query it.

```
select fn_month_name_to_number ('February') as month_no
```

This query will return 2 as month number.
You can pass values from a column as parameters to the function.

```
select fn_month_name_to_number (*columnname*) as month_no from *tablename*
```

Have a good day!

Comment: There are many paths we can take from nebraska to alaska. I choose canada, you panama...

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in function for this.

You could use a CASE statement:

```
CASE WHEN MonthName= 'January' THEN 1
     WHEN MonthName = 'February' THEN 2
     ...
     WHEN MonthName = 'December' TNEN 12
END AS MonthNumber
```

or create a lookup table to join against

```
CREATE TABLE Months (
    MonthName VARCHAR(20),
    MonthNumber INT
);

INSERT INTO Months
    (MonthName, MonthNumber)
    SELECT 'January', 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'February', 2
    UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 'December', 12;

SELECT t.MonthName, m.MonthNumber
    FROM YourTable t
        INNER JOIN Months m
            ON t.MonthName = m.MonthName;
```

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith: The MONTH function takes a datetime or date type input, not a string with a month name as the OP has specified in his question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ([Month] VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @T
SELECT 'January'
UNION
SELECT 'February'
UNION
SELECT 'March'`

SELECT MONTH('01-' + [Month] + '-2010') As MonthNumeric,[Month] FROM @T
ORDER BY MonthNumeric
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar experience (sql server 2012). I did not have the luxury of controlling the input, I just had a requirement to report on it. Luckily the dates were entered with leading 3 character alpha month abbreviations, so this made it simple & quick:

```
TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE(obs.DateValueText,SUBSTRING(obs.DateValueText,1,3),CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(obs.DateValueText,1,3),'...JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC')/4))
```

It worked for 12 hour:
    Feb-14-2015 5:00:00 PM  **2015-02-14 17:00:00.000**
and 24 hour times:
    Sep-27-2013 22:45   **2013-09-27 22:45:00.000**

(thanks ryanyuyu)

Comment: Formatting your SQL would make your answer actually readable.  I suggest formatting it in another text editor, then pasting the formatted code here (and clicked the format code button if needed).

Comment: Helped me because 3 char alpha month abbreviations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may even have a separate table like a `monthdetails (Monthno int, monthnames char(15))` and include values:

```
1 January
2 February
```

.... and so on, and then join this table with your existing table in the `monthnames` column

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.Monthno from table1 
left outer join monthdetails t2
on t1.monthname=t2.monthnames
order by t2.Monthno
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try sth like this, if you have month_name which is string datetype.After converting, you can feel free to order by Month.

For example, your table like this:

```
 month
 Dec
 Jan
 Feb
 Nov
 Mar
  .
  .
  .
```

My syntax is:

```
 Month(cast(month+'1 2016' as datetime))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, if you have the date (e.g. SubmittedDate)

```
DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(SubmittedDate) - 1, 0)) AS ColumnDisplayMonth
```

Or you can do it this way, if you have the month as an int

```
DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, @monthInt - 1, 0)) AS ColumnDisplayMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a bit too late but the most efficient way of doing this through a CTE as follows:

```
 WITH Months AS
    (
       SELECT 1 x
       UNION all
       SELECT x + 1
       FROM Months
       WHERE x < 12

     )
     SELECT x AS MonthNumber, DateName( month , DateAdd( month , x , -1 ))            AS MonthName FROM Months
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(month_added, 'Month')) AS month_number
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have EXTRACT functions

Answer (score -3):

```
select  Convert(datetime, '01 ' +  Replace('OCT-12', '-', ' '),6)
```

Comment: The question has been already correctly answered with several upvotes and on top of that, this answer is erroneous, the result to this query is `2012-10-01 00:00:00.000`, nothing to do with the question