# Convert Month Name to Month Number

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Month Name to Month Number Function in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314310/convert-month-name-to-month-number-function-in-sql)

I am attempting to convert a month name to month number in the area of the script below called `datename(MM, patientinfo.PatientDOB)`. As an example, it is currently returning as `January` and I would like it to return as `01` or `1`.

From what I've read I may need to do a `CASE WHEN 'January' THEN 1`, but I am not sure where to insert it or the exact syntax to use.

```
select
    Update_Log.RecordID as 'Dictation ID',
    cast(dictations.DOS as DATE) as 'Date of Service',
    groups.GroupName,
    rtrim(aspnet_Users.Firstname)+' '+rtrim(aspnet_Users.LastName) as Provider, 
    Update_Log.Updated, 
    Update_XRef.columnName as 'Update Type', 
    "New Value" =
        case 
            when update_xref.columnname = 'FacilityID' then (select facility.FacilityName+' [gID:'+update_log.NewValue+']' from facility where update_log.NewValue = facility.FacilityID)
            when update_xref.columnname = 'DOS' then (select left(update_log.NewValue, 11) as 'New Value')
            when update_xref.columnname = 'DictatorID' then (select rtrim(aspnet_users.Firstname)+' '+rtrim(aspnet_users.lastname) from aspnet_Users where aspnet_users.userid1 = update_log.UpdatedBy)
            when update_xref.columnname = 'PatientID' then (select rtrim(patientinfo.PatientFirst)+' '+rtrim(patientinfo.PatientLast)+' ['+datename(MM, patientinfo.PatientDOB)+'/'+datename(DD, patientinfo.PatientDOB)+'/'+datename(YY, patientinfo.PatientDOB)+ ', gID:'+rtrim(patientinfo.PatientID)+']' from patientinfo where patientinfo.PatientID = Update_Log.NewValue)
        end,
    "Old Value" =
        case 
            when update_xref.columnname = 'FacilityID' then (select facility.FacilityName+' [gID:'+update_log.OldValue+']' from facility where update_log.OldValue = facility.FacilityID)
            when update_xref.columnname = 'DOS' then (select left(update_log.OldValue, 11) as 'Old Value')
            when update_xref.columnname = 'DictatorID' then (select rtrim(aspnet_users.Firstname)+' '+rtrim(aspnet_users.lastname) from aspnet_Users where aspnet_users.userid1 = update_log.UpdatedBy)
            when update_xref.columnname = 'PatientID' then (select rtrim(patientinfo.PatientFirst)+' '+rtrim(patientinfo.PatientLast)+' ['+left(datename(MM, patientinfo.PatientDOB),3)+'/'+datename(DD, patientinfo.PatientDOB)+'/'+datename(YY, patientinfo.PatientDOB)+ ', gID:'+rtrim(patientinfo.PatientID)+']' from patientinfo where patientinfo.PatientID = Update_Log.OldValue)
        End
from 
    Update_Log, 
    Update_XRef, 
    aspnet_Users, 
    groups, 
    Dictations
where 
    Update_log.XRefID = Update_XRef.xRefID
    and Update_Log.UpdatedBy = aspnet_Users.userid1
    and aspnet_users.Groupid = Groups.GroupID
    and dictations.Dictationid = Update_Log.RecordID
    and Update_Log.Updated > dictations.DateofSignature
order by 
    groups.GroupName, 
    aspnet_users.LastName, 
    update_log.RecordID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `patientinfo.PatientDOB` is a full & typed date, to get the integer month part of the date;

```
datepart(MM, patientinfo.PatientDOB)
```

or

```
month(patientinfo.PatientDOB)
```

wrapped in `cast(?? as varchar(2))` for a character string.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When using the month or datepart, I receive the following messageL

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'JOHN SMITH [October/' to data type int.

Comment: `datepart` returns an integer, you cannot add it to a string without converting it to a string;  `select 'text or a char field ' + cast(datepart(MM, patientinfo.PatientDOB) as varchar(2)) + ' XXX...'`

Comment: Thank you Alex! You rock! I see now that you mentioned the cast in the first post, but I did not have the knowledge to put two and two together :)

Comment: Your welcome. `right('0' + cast(datepart(MM, patientinfo.PatientDOB) as varchar(2)), 2)` to pad with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this previously here:

[Convert month name to month number in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314310/convert-month-name-to-month-number-function-in-sql/8314350#8314350)

Let me know if this works for you!