# Deriving value of 1 column from another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with the following structure. I want to add one more column Month End in a SQL Server database such that Month End = the Last date of the month in DD-MMM format. can you suggest a query for this operation?

```
ID | Month 
---+-------
0  | Mar
1  | July     
2  | Jun        
3  | Aug     
.
.
.so on
```

Comment: Last date of the month depends on year for February

Comment: Have you researched the available date functions such as [EOMonth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)? Please show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @MartinSmith, we will consider 28th only for february.

Comment: @Stu my input is just the month name and not the date and the output should be the end date in DD-MMM format. I couldn't find such a function when I tried to search.

Comment: @Stu is right. You have the month name, you can [convert to num](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314310/convert-month-name-to-month-number-in-sql-server) and from that the EOMonth.

Comment: This seems to be the wrong way around anyway. You should be storing the date as date datatype (with canonical year if you don't care about that) and then you can derive the month name and DD-MMM formatted string for presentation purposes from that (With no need to store either as a string)

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service but your goal just isn't that difficult. Did you consider asking someone at a giant multi-national outsourcing firm for help? If you want to ignore the year, then this is a simple case expression involving three different logical conditions - is date in Feb then 28, is date in (Jan, Mar, ...) then 31 else 30. Have a go!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
```

This will give you end date of respected month of date.

Answer (score 0):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   ID    INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,Month VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO test
(ID,Month) VALUES 
(0,'Mar'),
(1,'July'),
(2,'Jun'),
(3,'Aug');
```

since `month` column type is not clearly indicated as

```
Select name, alias, months, shortmonths
from   sys.syslanguages
where name='us_english'
```

| name | alias | months | shortmonths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| us_english | English | January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December | Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec |

and change it into

| shortmonth | fullName |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | January |
| Feb | February |
| Mar | March |
| Apr | April |
| May | May |
| Jun | June |
| Jul | July |
| Aug | August |
| Sep | September |
| Oct | October |
| Nov | November |
| Dec | December |

by using  `string_split`, `row_number`

```
SELECT shortmonth,
       fullname
FROM   (SELECT NAME,
               alias,
               months,
               shortmonths,
               a.value                     AS shortmonth,
               Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
        FROM   (SELECT NAME,
                       alias,
                       months,
                       shortmonths
                FROM   sys.syslanguages
                WHERE  NAME = 'us_english') b
               CROSS apply String_split(shortmonths, ',') a) t1
       JOIN (SELECT NAME,
                    alias,
                    months,
                    shortmonths,
                    c.value                     fullName,
                    Row_number()
                      OVER (
                        ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
             FROM   (SELECT NAME,
                            alias,
                            months,
                            shortmonths
                     FROM   sys.syslanguages
                     WHERE  NAME = 'us_english') b
                    CROSS apply String_split(months, ',') c) t2
         ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```

use above query in `CTE` and join it with your table with first three `left` character and then use `EOMONTH` and `Right` function as follows

```
SELECT t.*,
       m.fullname,
       RIGHT(Eomonth(( '01-' + m.fullname + '-2010' )), 5)
FROM   test t
       JOIN monthname1 m
         ON LEFT(t.month, 3) = m.shortmonth
```

however using a proper year considering leap year should not be neglected.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f0d4c263bf8f444bd2fb14bedee93453)