# Is there a way to cast string to date to int in athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm working on use case where i need to convert the string type to integer type in `AWS Athena`

Below is my input data -

```
year    month
2022    jan
2022    feb
2012    apr
2023    may
2019    jun
```

Below is what I'm expecting -

```
year    month   yearmon
2022    jan     202201
2022    feb     202202
2012    apr     201204
2023    may     202305
2019    dec     201912
```

Initially I thought to use case statement wherein I hardcode for each month, concatenate this with year column and finally parse the yearmon as `int`. Something like -

```
concat(year, case when month = 'jan' then '01'
...
... end)
```

Finally cast it to `int`

I tried below formats -

```
Select month("jan")
```

```
Select cast("jan" as date)
```

But nothing seem to have worked.

Is there a better way to cast this use case than hard coding the values in case statement?

Comment: cast your year, month and 01 as a date and then format/convert.  so `select cast(concat_ws('-','01',table.month,table.year) as date) from table`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Got error `INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Value cannot be cast to date: 01-jan-2023`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314310/convert-month-name-to-month-number-in-sql-server

Comment: Try the solution given in above one.

Comment: @NishantGupta Already saw this thread. Doesn't work for my use case.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @NishantGupta the link is for SQL Server which has different SQL dialect compared to Presto/Trino on which Athena is based on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`date_parse` and `date_format`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions). The following works in Trino on which the Athena is based on:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(year, month) as (
    values (2022, 'jan'),
    (2022, 'feb'),
    (2012, 'apr'),
    (2023, 'may'),
    (2019, 'jun')
)

-- query
select date_format(
             date_parse(cast(year as varchar) || '-' || month, '%Y-%b'),
             '%Y%m'
           )
from dataset;
```

Which produces the following output (TBH I was a bit surprised that it can handle lowercase month names):

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 202201 |
| 202202 |
| 201204 |
| 202305 |
| 201906 |

If this will not work for your actual data then using case-when is the approach you might want to take.